# Nested directives not inheriting parent scope properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

Having a problem with nested directives and inheriting the scope from a parent. It happens that the scope I want to inherit from is an isolated scope. I've the code below

**test.html**

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl as test">
  <special-select data-selected-item="test.selectedThing">
     <special-select-selected-item></special-select-selected-item>
  </special-select>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
angular
    .module('testApp', ['special-inputs'])
    .controller('testCtrl', [
        function() {
            this.items = [
                { id: 1, name: 'alex 1', displayName:"alex 1 dn", imageUrl: 'http://placehold.it/505x100' }
            ];

            this.selectedThing = this.items[0];

            this.test = function() {
                console.log('test fn');
            }
        }
     ]);
```

**special-inputs.js**

```
angular
        .module('special-inputs', [])
        .directive('specialSelect', [
            function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    replace: true,
                    transclude: true,
                    template: '<div class="container" ng-transclude></div>',
                    scope: {
                        selectedItem: '='
                    },
                    link: {
                      pre: function(scope) {
                        console.log('parent link pre - ', scope.selectedItem);
                      },
                      post: function(scope) {
                        console.log('parent link post - ', scope.selectedItem);
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
        .directive('specialSelectSelectedItem', [
            function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    replace: true,
                    transclude: true,
                    template: '<div class="selected" ng-transclude></div>',
                    scope: true,
                    link: {
                      pre: function(scope) {
                        console.log('child link pre - ', scope.selectedItem);
                      },
                      post: function(scope) {
                        console.log('child link post - ', scope.selectedItem);
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

As you can see the nested directive is trying to create it's own isolate scope but grab the "selectedItem" from the isolate scope of the parent.

The docs say it should inherit and transclusion is semi prototypical, so I'm wondering why it's not working. Thanks. Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE**
I've updated the code to show the problem I'm having now. It seems that the scope item is set in the pre + post link functions on the parent, but never get put down to the child. The console outputs

```
2015-12-29 15:13:44.258 special-select.js:35 parent link pre -  Object {id: 1, name: "alex 1", displayName: "alex 1 dn", imageUrl: "http://placehold.it/505x100"}
2015-12-29 15:13:44.258 special-select.js:64 child link pre -  undefined
2015-12-29 15:13:44.260 special-select.js:67 child link post -  undefined
2015-12-29 15:13:44.260 special-select.js:38 parent link post -  Object {id: 1, name: "alex 1", displayName: "alex 1 dn", imageUrl: "http://placehold.it/505x100"}
```

I've tried using `scope.$watch` and `attrs.$observe` to populate the valu

Comment: If the child directive doesn't need an isolate scope then don't give it one? You can set `scope: true` on the child directive and it will inherit from the parent scope. If you want the scopes to be the same then you need to set `scope: false` on the child directive and it will have the same exact scope as it's parent. The former seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Cheers @Rorschach120, scope: true seemed to do it. Just wondering, shouldn't what I have up there work? it's creating an isolate scope, but taking the designated item from the parent.

Comment: It doesn't work because the value isn't actually being passed to the scope of the child directive. Using `$parent` would work, but is very bad practice. You need to pass `selectedItem` to the child's isolate scope through the two-way binding you've setup in the `scope` definition. 

`<special-select data-selected-item="test.selectedThing">
     <special-select-selected-item selected-item="selectedItem"></special-select-selected-item>
  </special-select>`

Comment: Okay great. Thanks! Appreciate the help

Comment: @vernak2539 - In your html, you have <special-select data-selected-item="test.selectedThing">, which means you want to pass test.selectedThing to  dataSelectedItem in your directive.  But in your directive, you defined selectedItem in the scope property.  Should have been dataSelectedItem.